# How do I get values out of a JToken if i dont know the index

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net

Imagine this is my json Object. AccessoryList has two items. What i want to do is I want to ignore some fields while comparing two such objects based on user's input. For eg. 
If User's input is to ignore field AccessoryList.Strap if AccessoryList.Item == “Bracelet”.

So when i encounter the field AccessoryList.Strap , i should ignore comparing it only if  the AccessoryList.Item matches to "Bracelet".

```
{{
  "HasArms": false,
  "Height": 34,
  "DistinguishingFeatures": null,
  "Traits": {
    "Nags": false,
    "Smokes": false,
    "NumArrests": 0
  },
  "AccessoryList": [
    {
      "Item": "Watch",
      "Colour": "Black",
      "Body": null
    },
    {
      "Item": "Bracelet",
      "Colour": "Red",
      "Body": null
    }
  ]
}}
```

But the problem here is I dunno which index i'm dealing with. so how  to get the value of jToken *Item* corresponding to *Strap*.

```
 var temp = token.Root.SelectToken("AccessoryList.Item").ToString();
```

Comment: Imagine there are multiple indices , For eg. ignore _AccessoryList.Strap.Type_ if _Accessorylist.item_ ==  _"Bracelet"_

Comment: Something like this?  [Querying JSON with JSONPath](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonSelectTokenJsonPath.htm).

Comment: *"I want to ignore some fields while comparing"* - compare what? Show your code. Also, read [mcve].